# How to deal with template return?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Maybe because I am a newer , not able to define which kind of question it belongs. So I didn't find the wanted result after searching.

It is my linked list Implementation with C++ template

```
template<class T> struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node<T>* pre;
    Node<T>* next;

};
template<class T> class Flist
{
    private:
        Node<T>* front;
        Node<T>* end; 
        int count;

    public:
        Flist();   
        ~Flist();
        Flist(const Flist& C_list); 
        inline void Deeply_Copy(const Flist& Copylist);
        bool Isempty() const;
        int Listsize() const;
        Node<T>& Listfront()const;
        Node<T>& Listend() const;
        void push_front(T N);
        void push_back(T N);
        void del_front();
        void del_back();
        Node<T>* Listfind(T x); 
        T ShowKey(int n);   

};


template<class T> T Flist<T>::ShowKey(int n)
{
    if (front == 0)
        {
            cout << "there is no element is the list.." << endl;
            return ???;
        }
    Node<T>* temp = front;
    while(n--)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp->value;

}
```

The function ShowKey(int n) I want it to return(not just show) the n-th element's value, But if the list is empty, I don't know what to return. I don't want to use exit to stop the procedure. Is there a more frindly way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Create a distinguished `T` that represents 'not found'. Or return an iterator.

Comment: This line `temp = temp->next;` will dereference a NULL pointer if `n` is greater than the number of items in the list.

Comment: @jww not all T can have a distinguished value, what if `T` = `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change the function signature to

```
bool showKey(int n, T& value);
```

and use it to set the value variable and return true if an entry exists at index n, and return false (and leave value unchanged) if the entry doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is likely to be to throw an exception; `std::domain_error` or `std::range_error` might be suitable.